# Word request for "someone meant to do something doesn't do it"

Tags: phrase-request, spoken-english

Talking about a surgeon, one said that Dr. Sam never did any surgery himself, rather he get it done by his assistants, that is to say, he is a surgeon **only in copy and pen.**

In our native language we use the phrase **"only in copy and pen."**

What are the natural ways of expressing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "On paper" is the closest, I would say.  You could say "by title" or "in title" and it would be understood.  "Technically" is a good adverb.  "By training" works pretty well.  Then there are the negative ways: "a surgeon, but not a practicing one", for example

Comment: **Nominally** (meaning **in name only**) would fit.  Note that your example lacks the word **would** after **he**.

Answer (score 1):

```
... he is a surgeon in name only.
```

There is a comment that mentions this phrase, and also "nominally", but it is harder to 'naturally' use "nominally" in the sentence as you have it. One could say something like

```
He is nominally a surgeon, but has always had actual surgery performed by his assistants.
```